# How to save node js https request in variable

Tags: node.js

I'm using an api written in node.js (normally only code in php) and try to get data from an external source.

The specific part is the following:

```
var https = require("https");
var token = "Secret_Token";
var request = https.get("https://example.com?token=" + token, function(response)
{ 
var body = ""; 
response.on('data', function(chunk) 
     {
     dapi.message.send('' + chunk)
     }); 
});
```

Instead of the `dapi.message.send('' + chunk)` that would sent the data directly to the api I try to save it to a variable.

I tried the ways I know to save it but it doesn't work.

The GET Requests gets the following result in my tests, so it needs to be saved in an array:
`["Testuser_1","Testuser_2","Testuser_3","Testuser_4","Testuser_5"]`

I tried to swap the `dapi.message.send('' + chunk)` part with `var myarray = chunk` or `var myarray = ('' + chunk)` and other possibilities but it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with a stream of data, the `on('data')` event might be triggered more than once. Because of this, you'll need to capture each event and assemble all of the chunks that you received:

```
var finalResponse = ''
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
  finalResponse += chunk
});
```

Since you want to wait for all of the data to be returned, you'll need to wait for the streams `end` event. This event indicates that no more data will be sent though the stream. Once your stream of data has ended, you can call the `dapi.message` function with the contents of the entire response that you saved into the `finalResponse` variable. You'll know when the stream of data has ended because just like the `data` event, an `end` event is triggered once there is no more data.

```
response.on('end', function() {
  dapi.message.send(finalResponse)
});
```

---

For convenience, I'll include a link to the Stream documentation on the `end` event - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end